# JSON encoding a string with the # and other special characters

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, encoding

I have the following client side javascript code.

```
    <html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        //var parameters = "a=" + JSON.stringify({ Code: "xyyyzz"}); 
        var parameters = "a=" + JSON.stringify({ Code: "x#yyy#zz"}); 
        alert(parameters);

        $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080', parameters)
        .done(function(str){
            alert("success");
            })
        .fail(function(e) {
            alert("failure");
            });

        });
</script>
</html>
```

and the following server side node.js code

```
var http = require('http');
var URL = require('url');
var queryString = require( "querystring" );

handler = function(req, res) {
                url = URL.parse(req.url);
                var queryObj = queryString.parse( url.query );
                var obj = JSON.parse( queryObj.a );
                console.log( obj.Code);
};

host = '127.0.0.1';
port = 8080;
http.createServer(handler).listen(port, host);
console.log('Server running at http://' + host + ':' + port + '/');
```

Now, if I load the .html file, the JSON call is made from the javascript. However, the parameter is not passed in full. It is passed only until the first # character and so causes the nodejs server to crash on the parse function. Now if I uncomment the previous line in the .js where a string without the # is passed, the nodejs server can succesfully parse the parameters.

So my question is, Is JSON incapable of encoding special characters like # in a string ? Or is this a bug ? Or do I need to add anything else to fix this so that x#yyy#zz is passed as a whole string to the nodejs server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data needs to be url encoded, `#` has a special meaning in urls.

If you pass an object to $.getJSON it will be automatically encoded for you

```
var parameters = {"a" : JSON.stringify({ Code: "x#yyy#zz"})};
```

or you could manually encode it

```
var parameters = "a=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({ Code: "x#yyy#zz"}));
```